# Binomial coefficient equality

Tags: binomial-coefficients

QUESTION: 
\begin{equation*}
\dbinom{n+m+1}{n}=\sum_{k=0}^n \dbinom{r+k}{k} \dbinom{m+n-r-k}{n-k}
\end{equation*}
where $n, m, r \geq 0$

I tried proving using binomial coefficient formula $\big[\dbinom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\big]$, but dont think its possible with summation, however if it is would it work? Maybe lattice paths would work better, but my understanding of lattice squares is minimal.

So i attempted the proof using binomial theorems and exponent combination laws and i get stuck

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^n \dbinom{r+k}{k} \dbinom{m+n-r-k}{n-k}=\dbinom{n+m+1}{n}
\end{equation*}
working with the right side .
\begin{equation*}\dbinom{n+m+1}{n}= \sum_n\dbinom{n+m+1}{n}x^n=(1+x)^{n+m+1}\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}=(1+x)^n(1+x)^m(1+x)\end{equation*} 
or would the next step be \begin{equation*}(1+x)^n(1+x)^{m+1}\end{equation*}

Comment: I think the LHS should be $\dbinom{n+m}n$, in which case this is just a simple variation of [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas no, the LHS is correct: this a "double convolution" (upper and lower terms), in which case the upper term gets a +1.

Comment: @MahlissaJayde: The right-hand side $(1+x)^{n+m+1}$ of your calculation is not valid, since $n$ is the index of the sum and so $n$ can't occur on the right-hand side.

Comment: i just realized that. so this approach will not work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\binom{r+k}{k}\binom{m+n-r-k}{n-k}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{-r-1}{k}(-1)^k\binom{-m+r-1}{n-k}(-1)^{n-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=(-1)^n\binom{-m-2}{n}\tag{2}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{n+m+1}{n}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ twice.

  This way we get for example $\binom{r+k}{k}=\binom{-(-r-k)}{k}=\binom{(-r-k)+k-1}{k}(-1)^k=\binom{-r-1}{k}(-1)^k$ with $-r-k=p$ and $k=q$.
- In (2) we apply the *[Chu-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity#Chu.E2.80.93Vandermonde_identity)*.
- In (3) we apply again the binomial identity as in (1).

Comment: perfect (as always!)

Comment: @GCab: You're too friendly, thanks. But sometimes there are nice miniatures, which I don't see straightaway. *[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499476/how-to-calculate-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-binom-nk-kk-frac1nk/2500164#2500164)* is a nice example where SangchulLee provided a very nice answer to my hint. :-)

Comment: Markus, yes, I saw that elegant shortcut provided by Sangchul Lee: that is the nice aspect of this site, learning from each other. And in this regard I would like to know your approach to [this other interesting post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2501405) if I may permit to abuse of your "intellectual curiosity" .

Comment: thank you, ive always liked algebra until it became abstract

Comment: @MahlissaJayde: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is helpful! :-)

Comment: i never learned chu vandermonde, is this the only way ? i clicked the link and i saw upside L's and something about Gauss, where there was no further information

Comment: @MahlissaJayde: There's always more than one way to do it. Not so clear what you want to know. Some more information to Chu Vandermonde or alternative proofs of your problem?

Comment: well i just edited my question with my attempt  of proving, but then i end up at a dead end

Comment: unless i'm over thinking and the chu vandermonde identity is just a method that lets you apply operations on binomial identities. Correct me if im wrong please, multiplied $(-1)^k(-1)^{n-k}$ and somehow got the difference of $\dbinom{-r-1}{k}$ and $\dbinom{-m+r-1}{n-k}$

Comment: @MahlissaJayde: I've extended my comment somewhat which might be useful.

Comment: i understood that step, thank you its just the elimination of k in step 2